# GCD of two number when one of it is very large

Tags: string, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

GCD of two numbers a and b, where **(0 <= A <= 40000 and A <= B < 10^250)**.
**Below is a code part that is used to deal with large values**. But I am not getting how this method works. Please explain this concept. **I have also given complete program below.**
**Code:**

```
char s[261];
int a,temp=0;
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%s",s);
if(a!=0){
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
    temp=(temp*10)+(s[i]-'0');
    temp%=a;
}
printf("%d\n",gcd(temp,a));
}
else 
    printf("%s\n",s);
```

**Complete Program**

```
int gcd(int a,int b){
    if(b==0)
        return a;
    else return gcd(b,a%b);
}

int main(){
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--){
    char s[261];
    int a,temp=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%s",s);
    if(a!=0){
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        temp=(temp*10)+(s[i]-'0');
        temp%=a;
    }
    printf("%d\n",gcd(temp,a));
    }
    else 
        printf("%s\n",s);
    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Can you share the problem statement link?

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, it's computing gcd(A, B mod A) (using the Euclidean algorithm as Photon points out), which equals gcd(A, B) by the same basic number theory involved in the proof of the Euclidean algorithm.

To compute B mod A, it interleaves the string-to-integer computation with the modulo computation by exploiting the ring structure of the integers modulo A, specifically (10 x + y) mod A = (10 (x mod A) + y) mod A. For example,

```
789 mod 9 =  (((7 * 10) + 8)        * 10 + 9) mod 9
          = ((((7 * 10) + 8) mod 9) * 10 + 9) mod 9
          = ((78             mod 9) * 10 + 9) mod 9
          = ((6                     * 10 + 9) mod 9
          = (69                             ) mod 9
          = 6,
```

which we arrived at without doing arithmetic on three-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 10^250 is much larger than any standard integer type in C. So when parsing `b`, it computes it modulo `a` so it fits in an `int`. That works because if `b>a`, then `gcd(a, b)` is equal to `gcd(a, b%a)`.